# Different results from forecast::checkresiduals and Box.test

Tags: testing, time-series, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to fit an ar modelo with exogenous regressors, in particular seasonal dummies and trend with AR(3) error. For this I'm using the following code:

```
modelo<-Arima(log.licor, order = c(3,0,0), xreg = tend_esta, include.mean = F)
```

there is no mean included since I'm not leaving any seasonal dummy out of the regression.

The result of

```
forecast::checkresiduals(modelo, test = "LB")
```

is:

```
    Ljung-Box test
data:  Residuals from Regression with ARIMA(3,0,0) errors
Q* = 77.787, df = 7, p-value = 3.886e-14

Model df: 17.   Total lags used: 24
```

but the result of

```
Box.test(residuals(modelo), type = "Ljung-Box")
```

is

```
    Box-Ljung test

data:  residuals(modelo)
X-squared = 1.3407, df = 1, p-value = 0.2469
```

am I doing something wrong with the arguments? the implication of each results are completly different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Play around with the `lag` and `fitdf` parameters in `Box.test`. So for your problem, see how it says "Model df: 17" and "Total lags used: 24" in the forecast version? Try those in the Box.test version.